# 'Array Index out of Range' on 'RefreshControl'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView where I am fetching data from api. Everything working fine with fetching/displaying data and pagination/infinite-scroll. However, when I try to use my RefreshControl, it crashes with an error:

> Array index out of range

```
 var theRefreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
 var results: [JSON]! = []
    // more stuff..

 func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
        if isFirstLoad == false {
            self.results = []
            currentPage = 1
            getPosts()
        }
        self.theRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : PostCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as! PostCell

    cell.delegate = self

    print(indexPath.row) // check below.

    let post = self.results![indexPath.row]    // 'array index out of range' here.

 }
```

To get more detail about the error, I tried adding `print(indexPath.row)`. What I receive is, I receive from `0` to `10` in first load, and then as soon as I refresh, it gets weird:

[image]

Also, when I click on the (i):

> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9}

Interestingly, exactly same approach works in my other TableViewControllers, only this one is bugging. What may be the problem?

---

```
func getPosts() {
    isLoading = true

Alamofire.request(.GET, link & params: ["page":"\(currentPage ?? 1)"])
  .responseJSON { response in

      // error checks

    if let data = json["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {

        self.lastPage = json["last_page"].int!
        self.currentPage = json["current_page"].int!

        if self.currentPage == 1 {
           self.results = data
           self.tableView.reloadData() 
        } else {                             
           var currentCount = self.results!.count;
           var indxesPath : [NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath]()

           for result in data {
             indxesPath.append(NSIndexPath(forRow:currentCount,inSection:0));
              self.results?.append(result)
              currentCount++
           }

     self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indxesPath, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)                       
    }
```

**Edit:** Please note that I tried `results.removeAll()` as well as `results.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)` in refresh button action function, but no luck. I am still getting the same error and same log for `print(indexPath.row) - 0 to 10 in first load, and in refresh, weirdly 6, 7, 8, [], 9

Comment: It means you are creating more cells than your data source's count. Check `getPosts()` and `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`. Your data count must match the table's row count.

Comment: my `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` has `return self.results?.count ?? 0` inside, and it works just fine unless I use refresh; and on my other TableViewControllers with refresh too. It also crashes if I comment `getPosts()` out

Comment: Can you show `getPosts()`?

Comment: Added in question. But I don't think the problem is here because exactly same function is working in my other viewcontroller .

Comment: I think when I call refresh, it's not emptying the results as fast or something; or the cell and results doesn't communicate as fast. Because, on my other controller (where refresh works), the user only sees 3 rows at a time on the screen, however in here 10 rows. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Try using `results.removeAll()` instead of `results = []`.

Comment: @Caleb, when I try this I get the same result.. If I print(indexPath.row), I receive 0-10 in first load and then as soon as I refresh, 6, 7, 8, [], 9 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by deleting`self.results = []` from `refresh()` function. Interestingly, if I empty the array before I refresh, it was creating a problem, but if I directly overwrite the data in the array, it works!

Comment: This isn't working with Swift 3.0 if a cell is already selected when refreshing. Also tried disabling selections for the duration of the refresh, same thing happens.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.0 - Same issue here, solved in a similar way to @mcclux but with one less step.

Use the inbuilt UIRefreshControl.
`var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!`, then within viewDidLoad configure it:

```
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl.init()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourViewControllerName.yourFunctionToCallOnRefresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Then you can wrap your code within cellForRowAt indexPath with

`if !self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
...
}`

Worked perfectly for me after struggling through it crashing for hours. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; it was caused in my case by tableView being called during the refresh, during the period when the content was being reset. Because the index was empty for a period, the app was occasionally throwing index out of range. It didn't happen every time. I solved it by creating a boolean var (isRefreshing) that gets set to true when the refresh starts and then set to false once the refresh is over. Inside of `tableView()` I have a wrapper for the functionality. In your case it would look like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if !self.isRefreshing {
        let cell : PostCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as! PostCell
        cell.delegate = self
        print(indexPath.row) // check below.
        let post = self.results![indexPath.row]    // 'array index out of range' here.
    }
 }
```

Edit: here's how I'm using it. The cell creation and return are outside of the if:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SessionTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SessionTableViewCell
    if !self.isReloading {
            ...
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: It won't let me place the return cell in the if condition, also doesn't let me to place let cell : Postcell ~ part either if I place the cell :/ What should I do?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It's still getting inside the false condition and crashes at the same place :/

Comment: Is it intermittent, or every time? In my case I sometimes had to hold the refresh in order for it to crash.

Comment: No, it's crashing everytime I refresh, but doesn't when it loads for the first time. Also pagination (infinite scroll) is working. :/ Surprisingly, the same chunk is working in my other controller. The difference is that this page has 10 rows while other one has 3 rows that the user can see at a time (not sure if it makes a difference)

Comment: One option for debugging a little further would be to wrap 
let post = self.results![indexPath.row]
in an if statement to make sure that self.results is as long or longer than indexPath.row. If it's not, maybe dump self.results to see what's going on there.

Comment: Now, when I print(indexPath.row), I receive 0 to 10 in first load, but then when I run refresh, I receive `7,8, [], 9` and then `fatal error: Array index out of range` :/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue when the backing array was emptied like what you did w/ `self.results = []`. In my finding, there are 2 additional ways to solve this issue.

```
//1. is to reload table view as soon as you empty the array

 func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    if isFirstLoad == false {
        self.results = []
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        currentPage = 1
        getPosts()
    }
    self.theRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

//2. is to delay the execution of the code inside the if scope to give enough time for the table view to get up to date on the count of the results array

  func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
     if isFirstLoad == false {
        self.delayExecutionByMilliseconds(500) {
           self.results = []
           currentPage = 1
           getPosts()
        }
     }
     self.theRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
  }

  func delayExecutionByMilliseconds(_ delay: Int, for anonFunc: @escaping () -> Void) {
     let when = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(delay)
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: anonFunc)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your refresh function, add `self.tableView.reloadData()` after cleaning your arrays, and before the function getPosts()